# Batch script wont work properly

Tags: file, batch-file

I've written a script to delete the batch file created once the exe file is executed which was compiled with quick bfc since it doesn't do it by its self, containing the source code once process is non-existent. The problem is that it deletes it's self and ends two processes, its self and xxx.exe. My aim is for it to go through a loop of checking every 2 seconds whether the process exists or not. If the process is no longer running, it removes the h attribute of any of the possible files that it is enabled on in the %temp% folder and then it delete everything in the %temp% folder. If it does it goes through the same process again of checking whether xxx.exe exists or not.

```
@echo off
start xxx.exe
:A
tasklist 2>nul | find "xxx.exe" 1>nul
if  not ErrorLevel 1 (
echo Wscript.Sleep 2000> %temp%\sleep.vbs
start /w wscript.exe %temp%\sleep.vbs
del %temp%\sleep.vbs /f /q
goto A
) else (
Goto B
)
:B
attrib -h %temp%\*.*
del %temp%\*.* /f /q
exit
```

p.s
Added the goto B part since the first attempt for success didn't work either.
Keep in mind, when xxx.exe is launched it uses the batch file created in the %temp% folder so if xxx.exe is terminated it will still be able to function thus leaving only cmd.exe active.
The script used to check whether the process exists or not is obviously invisible.
The batch file launched offers menu's e.g 1. Do xxx
2. sddd
.

Answer (score 0):

Seems a bit odd to mix `VBScript` and batch scripting since you're not effectively solving the problem in one technology. Perhaps, if you migrated your entire solution to `VBScript` you would have a more elegant solution.

```
 Option Explicit
 Const WS_SHOW = 1
 Dim objShell
 Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
 objShell.Run "xxx.exe", WS_SHOW, True
 Dim objFSO
 Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 objFSO.DeleteFile "xxx.exe"
```

Comment: Thank you, will test but i would prefer a solution in batch for this.